# Magical leaves and pairings

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> You are in a magical forest where fairies have enchanted the leaves of
> the trees with different colours. There are 6 pairs of enchanted
> leaves (12 leaves in total) in the forest, each labelled with a
> distinct number from 1 to 6. When you pick leaves blindly from the
> trees and pair them randomly, what is the probability that the paired
> leaves have colours differing by at most 1?

What I've tried:
We know, as far as I am able to understand the question, there are 12 leaves with 12 different colours. 6 pairs are formed and each pair (i.e each individual leaf) is given a number between 1 and 6. Now we need to create 6 new pairs from our 12 leaves such that each pair has a difference between the numbers on the two leaves of atmost 1.

Let $F(n)$ denote the number of pairings such that the given condition is satisfied for $n$ pairs i.e $2n$ leaves. then, I get the recurrence $$F(n)=F(n-1)+2F(n-2)$$ The $F(n-1)$ term comes from pairing both leaves with number n together and the $2F(n-2)$ term comes from pairing each $n$ leaf with an $n-1$ leaf (which there are 2 ways to do, since both $n$ leaves and $n-1$ leaves all have different colors) Combining this with the base conditions $F(1)=1, F(2)=3$ I get $$F(6)=43$$ The only problem I am having is figuring out the denominator. I doubt it would just be the number of pairings, $\frac{12!}{2^6 6!}$. I also feel that there is something problematic with my recurrence somehow. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would argue that your $2F(n-2)$ term is misguided. Think about it again.

Comment: hmm, well if the $n$ leaves are not paired with each other, they must be paired with the $n-1$ leaves... so we can pair each $n$ leaf with one of the $n-1$ leaves and the other one pairs with the other one, giving 2 variations. I don't see the problem @CalvinLin

Comment: Is that 2 variations, or 1 variation?  $\quad$ I guess part of it boils down to how you're setting up the denominator, and how you're distinguishing pairs. (for which I might be doing it differently from you).  $\quad$ IE You're treating the pairs of leaves as distinct ($1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, 12$), whereas I'm preferring not to do so ($1, 1, 2, 2, \ldots, 6, 6$).

Comment: how are you setting up the denominator? If I use $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$ with $F(1)=F(2)=1$ then that would just give me a completely different factor, no? @CalvinLin

Comment: Simulating this (assuming I understood the problem correctly), I was usually getting a little over $4000$ admissible pairings per $1000000$ trials. For my simulation, for each trial, I shuffled the list $[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]$ and then checked whether the absolute value of the difference between successive (disjoint) pairs was always less than or equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

To a certain extent, this response is **off-point**, because I am not addressing *where the original poster* went wrong.  The reason that I am ducking the issue is that I don't understand the OP's reasoning behind the idea that

$$F(n)=F(n-1)+2F(n-2).$$

---

$\underline{\text{My Approach}}$

This is an unusual combinatorics/probability problem that is more easily solved by avoiding combinatorics, and focusing solely on probability of events.

I will first solve the case of $~n = 6,~$ and then solve the more general case.

$~1/3~$ of the time, the first leaf chosen will be numbered either 1 or 6.  When that happens, there will then be $~3~$ satisfying leaves from the remaining 11 leaves.

$~2/3~$ of the time, the first leaf chosen will **not** be numbered either 1 or 6.  When that happens, there will then be $~5~$ satisfying leaves from the remaining 11 leaves.

Therefore the desired computation (when $~n=6~$) is

$$\left[ ~\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{3}{11} ~\right] + \left[ ~\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{5}{11} ~\right]. \tag1 $$

The computation in (1) above easily generalizes to the case of $~2n~$ leaves.

$~2/n~$ of the time, the first leaf chosen will be numbered either 1 or n.  When that happens, there will then be $~3~$ satisfying leaves from the remaining $~(2n-1)~$ leaves.

$~(n-2)/n~$ of the time, the first leaf chosen will **not** be numbered either 1 or n.  When that happens, there will then be $~5~$ satisfying leaves from the remaining $~(2n-1)~$ leaves.

Therefore the desired computation is

$$\left[ ~\frac{2}{n} \times \frac{3}{2n-1} ~\right] + \left[ ~\frac{n-2}{n} \times \frac{5}{2n-1} ~\right]. \tag2 $$